# still on playing audio files on my android app

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

i'm new to this android thing and im going to create a sample app in which i can play an audio file. so, i'll show you a part of the class i created:

```
public class BBOX {
    public static final int FORWARD = 0x09;
    public static final int BACKWARD = 0x06;
    public static final int CLOCKWISE = 0x05;
    public static final int COUNTERCLOCKWISE = 0x0a;
    public static final int FIRE = 0x10;

    static MediaPlayer audioControl; 

    public static BBOX send(int data){

        Context context;
        if(data == FORWARD){
            audioControl = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.forward_100hz);
            audioControl.start();
        }
        else if(data == BACKWARD){
            audioControl = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.backward_200hz);
            audioControl.start();
```

the error is on the forward_100hz and backward_200hz... which are my audio files..
what did i miss?

Comment: which error you facing ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what else you're doing wrong, but at the very least, your context is null where you pass it to MediaPlayer.create.

If you're using this method statically, you'll need to pass the context in from your Activity when you call it.

Welcome to Stack, btw. Don't forget to mark answers that are helpful with up-votes.

Answer (score 0):

Just prepare the media player before playing the audio.

```
    try {
        audioControl = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.forward_100hz);
        audioControl.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     audioControl.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer paramMediaPlayer) {
            paramMediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
```